# How do I remove applications with broken applescript dictionaries

Tags: macos

I've recently begun trying to figure out how to add support for applescript commands to macos apps and so far haven't gotten very far. I have, however, managed to fubar my installation of applescript dictionaries. This results in having about 15 or so entries of my failures in the scripting tool and I can't seem to get rid of them.

How *do* I get rid of the dictionaries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the Scripting tool, you can get a list of all known dictionaries in Archive/Open Dictionary. The list contains a path entry, which will lead you to a file that you can delete. If you do, the dictionary will be removed from the system.